# Decrypt a string with a decrypted key CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 205

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encryption, base64

I'm trying to save game data on the user's device and encrypt it to make it secure, to make the data even more secure i am doing that the key used be different for everyone (so save it on the device and encrypt it using another key constant, the same for everyone). So you will first have to decrypt the key using a constant key, then decrypt the data using the key that was decrypted.

Before reporting I removed the non-essential parts from the script to make it more readable.

**this is the script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string FileName = "/datiDIGioco.txt";
    public string DataContent;

    public string chiave = "";
    public string KeyFileName = "/chiave.txt";
    string ConstantKey = "AnyConstantKeyEqualsForEveryone.";

    void Start()
    {
        if ((File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + KeyFileName)))
        {
            LoadData();
        }
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        chiave = File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + KeyFileName);//the content of the key file, so the encripted key
        DecriptKey(); //decrypt the chiave variable using a constant key

        DataContent = File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + FileName);//the content of the data file
        Decript(); //decrypts the ContenutoDati variable using the decrypted key
    }

    public void DecriptKey()
    {
        byte[] TestoCriptato = Convert.FromBase64String(chiave);

        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ConstantKey);
        byte[] iv = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];
        aes.IV = iv;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform tdc = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        byte[] testoDecriptato = tdc.TransformFinalBlock(TestoCriptato, 0, TestoCriptato.Length);
        tdc.Dispose();

        chiave = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(testoDecriptato);
    }

    public void Decript()
    {
        byte[] TestoCriptato = Convert.FromBase64String(DataContent);

        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(chiave);
        byte[] iv = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];
        aes.IV = iv;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform tdc = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        byte[] testoDecriptato = tdc.TransformFinalBlock(TestoCriptato, 0, TestoCriptato.Length);
        tdc.Dispose();

        DataContent = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(testoDecriptato);
    }
}
```

**this is the error**

```
CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 205.
 Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.ThrowBadPaddingException (System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode padding, System.Int32 length, System.Int32 position) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
 Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.FinalDecrypt (System.Byte[] inputBuffer, System.Int32 inputOffset, System.Int32 inputCount) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
 Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.TransformFinalBlock (System.Byte[] inputBuffer, System.Int32 inputOffset, System.Int32 inputCount) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
 PlayerScript.DecriptKey () (at Assets/script/salva dati/PlayerScript.cs:52)
 PlayerScript.LoadData () (at Assets/script/salva dati/PlayerScript.cs:33)
 PlayerScript.Start () (at Assets/script/salva dati/PlayerScript.cs:25)
```

Any help fixing this error would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: The logic itself works, which is probably why it's your data or an I/O issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/z7MkGh. Post test data. Note that static IVs are insecure. Also, a key should not be a sequence of ASCII encoded characters, but a randomly generated byte sequence.

Comment: I went to check and in fact it was a problem with the data, when I imported the key file it also imported unwanted text parts, now I've solved it. Thanks for your help